# How to check Blackberry device is connected to internet connection?

Tags: blackberry, internet-connection

In `Android`, checking internet connection is like that.

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

How about in Blackberry RIM?

p/s*: I am not asking for checking the type of connection or connection available.

Comment: see the API [**Class CoverageInfo**](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/CoverageInfo.html)

Comment: See the [Network Diagnostic Tool](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/What_Is_-_Network_Diagnostic_Tool.html?nodeid=1450596&vernum=0) and [Blackberry Connectivity Issues](http://develop-for-fun.blogspot.com/2011/05/blackberry-connectivity-issues.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For instance, to check only for BIS coverage:

```
boolean hasConnectivity = TransportInfo.isTransportTypeAvailable(TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_BIS_B) && TransportInfo.hasSufficientCoverage(TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_BIS_B);
```

You have more flags available in `TransportInfo` class for Wi-Fi, BES (MDS) and direct TCP. So the method to check for internet connectivity would check for all the available transport types.

Comment: Cannot, even the simulator is connected, it returns false;

Comment: @Alan Lai the code above is for BIS transport type only. Simulators are usually connected through direct TCP, unless MDS simulator is used (in that case, MDS transport type should be used)